# PrimeNG Toaster not showing - Angular 6

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to implement PrimeNG toaster but it is not showing up, not sure what I am missing. I followed the steps like this:

```
npm install primeng --save
npm install primeicons --save
```

I added to angular-cli styles the following:

```
"node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
"node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
"node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
```

In my app.module.ts I imported

```
ToastModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule
```

In providers I have MessageService from `primeng/api`.

Now, in my http requests service, I added this piece of code:

```
get(url: string, showSuccessToast?: boolean, toastMessage?: string) {
        const result = this.http.get(url)
            .pipe(map((response: Response) => {

                    if (showSuccessToast) {
                        this.messageService.add({severity: 'success', summary: 'Success!', detail: toastMessage});
                    }
                    return response;
                }),
                catchError(response => this.handleError(response))
            );

        return result;
    }
```

In my component service, where I make the get request, I added true for showSuccess and a string for message.

In `app.component.ts` I added: `<p-toast></p-toast>`

No errors are thrown, Toaster is just not popping up...

Comment: try removing the  showSuccessToast condition and just display the toast when you return a response

Comment: @Roj when I put breakpoint on that line (this.messageService.add.....), it does the add function but toaster is not showing up for some reason, showSuccessToast is working fine

Comment: I think you mean app.component.html rather than app.component.ts to add <p-toast></p-toast>

Answer (score 12):

It seems your toast is being shown but it just displays before your view gets initialised. I tried recreating your code and it seems adding a setTimeout fixed the issue

```
   setTimeout(() => {
      this.messageService.add({
        severity: "success",
        summary: "Success Message",
        detail: "Order submitted"
      });
    }, 1000);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It would be better to hook into lifecycle on AfterViewInit

Comment: AfterViewInit did it for me

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try this to see whether it will work:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, ...)
this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.messageService.add({
        severity: "success",
        summary: "Success Message",
        detail: "Order submitted"
      });
});
```

refer to this thread:
https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=56743&p=172855&hilit=Toast#p172855

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this answer for the ones distracted...

I had a similar problem with **PrimeNG** [MessageService](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v11-lts/#/messages).

On the `app.component.html` file I have these three `<p-messages>` elements:

```html
<p-messages [enableService]="true"
            [closable]="true"
            [key]="'success'"
            [escape]="false"></p-messages>

<p-messages [enableService]="true"
            [closable]="true"
            [key]="'warning'"
            [escape]="false"></p-messages>

<p-messages [enableService]="true"
            [closable]="true"
            [key]="'error'"
            [escape]="false"></p-messages>
```

that can be reused by child components when a message is to be displayed to the user.

The `app.module.ts` file has the `MessageService` as a provider.

```
providers: [
    ...
    MessageService ]
```

So far so good... the problem was that in a child component within another module I had also added the `MessageService` into its providers which was causing a message added through the injected `messageService` to not be displayed.

```
this.store.pipe(
        select(monitoringWarning), filter(it => !!it))
        .subscribe(message => {
            //debugger;
            this.messageService.add({ // this message added on a child component was not showing on the warning <p-messages> inside app.component.html
                closable: true,
                severity: 'warn',
                key: 'warning',
                detail: message
            })
        });
```

To solve it I just had to remove the additional `MessageService` added to the providers on the child module so that it could use the one already ***provided*** by the app module.

The page linked above even states the following:

> **Message Service**
>
> MessageService alternative does not require a value
> binding to an array. In order to use this service, import the class
> and define it as a provider in a component higher up in the component
> tree such as application instance itself so that descendant components
> can have it injected. If there are multiple message components having
> the same message service, you may use key property of the component to
> match the key of the message to implement scoping.